# How to convert a PowerPoint slide into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, powerpoint

I am trying to insert PowerPoint slides into HTML preserving links in the PowerPoint slide. I was just wondering if any of you knew a good method to maybe exporting a PowerPoint slide to an HTML and then displaying it in a `div` on your page, with a link to say do a JavaScript function on that same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not quite what you asked, Google Docs or Slideshare both let you embed Powerpoint as flash - perhaps that would be a more elegant way to do this. That is, if embedding is the aim!

Comment: I guess this will have to do, I was hoping more for a solution that I had more propriety control over, but microsofts export feature in powerpoint is just well retarded.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used it, but [PPT2HTML](http://www.pptools.com/ppt2html/index.html) might help. There's also this [blog](http://www.soniacoleman.com/Tutorials/PowerPoint/loop_html.htm) that describes how to save your presentation for the web then modify it.

This isn't exactly what you're after, but there are some html-based presentation tools like [S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/), [DOMSlides](http://icant.co.uk/domslides/) you might want to consider as they wouldn't suffer from being translated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery plugin called PPTXjs.

This plugin convert pptx to html using javascript only (no server side code needed).

It is based on [PPTX2HTML](https://github.com/g21589/PPTX2HTML) but support a lot more shapes, media (audio, video) and more.

Using:

```
    $("#result").pptxToHtml({
        pptxFileUrl: "path/to/slide.pptx"
    });
```

For more details : https://github.com/meshesha/PPTXjs.

Comment: How are you using the Library. I cannot use it. there is no example given in https://github.com/meshesha/PPTXjs.

Answer (score 2):

1)u can convert it to flash swf
2)convert all slides to an image file and then add 2 buttons(Back,Next) with calling the next and previous images based on an integer variable and this buttons will show u the previous and next slides :)

sorry but u cant embed it without copying all the Powerpoint-exported HTML code in your div tag

Answer (score 1):

I remember there was a function in PowerPoint to export it to an HTML, I would do that and then have it in the page using an `<iframe>` and then put that inside a `<div>`

Comment: yes in a way this could work, but then javascript calls in the link would only work for code in the iframe, unless you know a way to get a javascript call link in the iframe to work on the parent frame?

Comment: Hey,I am having a same situation...can you please elaborate a little..In my case,i want the user to upload the ppt file and extract those slides (for slideshow)and put it in div..if there is an alternate solution without upload,pleasse let me know..waiting for your reply..